# Is it possible to use the percent sign in my acronym list?

Tags: symbols, glossaries, acronyms, percent-sign

I have an established list of acronyms in my document and use `\newacronym` to add new terms. I was hoping I could add one for %MVC using the following command:

`\newacronym{\%MVC}{\%MVC}{Percentage of the Maximum Voluntary Contraction}`

But it creates errors and renders the acronym as "%MVC@name@entryfmt (%MVC@name@entryfmt)" within the document. This is a common acronym in the field so I would prefer not to change it. Is there a way of using it in my acronym list?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you given `\newacronym{pvmc}{\%MVC}{Percentage of the maximum voluntary contraction}` and `\gls{pvmc}` a try?

Comment: Using \newacronym{pMVC}{\%MVC}{Percentage of the Maximum Voluntary Contraction} and \acrfull{\pMVC} worked. Thank you so much :)